# How to convert a try-catch-finally block to using statement in c#?

Tags: c#, try-catch, using, try-catch-finally

Say we create a IDisposable object, and we have a try-catch-finally block

```
var disposable= CreateIDisposable();
try{
  // do something with the disposable.
}catch(Exception e){
  // do something with the exception
}finally{
  disposable.Dispose();
}
```

How do I convert this to a using block?

If it were

```
var disposable= CreateIDisposable();
try{
  // do something with the disposable.
}finally{
  disposable.Dispose();
}
```

I would convert to

```
using(var disposable= CreateIDisposable()){
     // do something with the disposable.
}
```

How would I do this with the catch block?

```
try{
  using(var disposable= CreateIDisposable()){
     // do something with the disposable.
   }
}catch(Exception e){
  // do something with the exception
}
```

Comment: You have two choices, either using the code that you show (with the `using` statement inside the `try` clause, or with the entire `try` / `catch` within the `using` block`.  If no exception is thrown, then the code is nearly identical (the `Dispose` call happens at the end, though the underlying assembly code will look different).  If there is an exception, then, in either case, the `catch` clause would execute first and then the `Dispose` call on the way *out the door*.  I'd call it a toss-up.  Of course, your `try` / `catch`/ `finally` code is perfectly good as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close.  It's the other way around.

In reality, the CLR doesn't have `try`/`catch`/`finally`.  It has `try`/`catch`, `try`/`finally`, and `try`/`filter` (that's what it does when the `when` clause is used on `catch`).  `try`/`catch`/`finally` in C# is just a `try`/`catch` within the `try` block of a `try`/`finally`.

So if you expand that and convert the `try`/`finally` to `using`, you get this:

```cs
using (var disposable = CreateIDisposable())
{
    try
    {
        // do something with the disposable.
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // do something with the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: @KristjanKica: I ran out of room in my comment on your question.  But, I was going to say that this is the way I normally write these (though I have done `try` / `catch` / `finally` before

Comment: that makes more sense. My code would exceute "finally" before "catch"